# Prevent YES/NO values to convert to true/false Coldfusion 9?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml, railo, lucee

I have the form where user have to select the value from the list. List is created by administrators. In one of the lists there is an option for user to pick `NO` value that stands for some reserved code. Something like `Not Occupied`. So I use JQuery and AJAX to communicate with the server. On the back end I use ColdFusion 9 on my production server. So in order to bring back `NO` I have to convert that to `'NO '` with the space. If I don't do this function will return `false` value on the client side. Here is example of my code conversion:

```
<cfset convertYesNo = {
    YES : "YES ",
    NO : "NO "
}>

<cfset qryRecs['value'] = URLEncodedFormat(structKeyExists(convertYesNo, myInfo[CurrentRow]) ? convertYesNo[myInfo[CurrentRow]] : myInfo[CurrentRow])>
```

Code above worked fine on my development site. The only difference is that on development we have ColdFusion 10 and on the live we have ColdFusion 9. So once I moved the code to live I started getting error message:

```
ColdFusion was looking at the following text&#x3a;<p>&#x7b;</p><p>The CFML compiler was processing&#x3a;<ul><li>A cfset tag beginning on line 1071, column 18.<li>A cfset tag beginning on line 1071, column 18.

<pre>1069 :         }&gt;
1070 :      
<b>1071 :       &lt;cfset convertYesNo = {</b>
1072 :          &quot;Yes&quot; : &quot;Yes &quot;,
1073 :          &quot;No&quot; : &quot;No &quot;
</pre>
```

I have tried to put quotes around YES and NO but that did not help. If anyone knows the way how to fix this problem please let me know. thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you use JavaCast("string", "No") or does that get automatically reconverted back to something undesirable? When converting to JSON, I use the JSONUtil library and use JavaCast("boolean", 1) to create the non-quote-enclosed TRUE/FALSE values in JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think structure notation for CF9 did not support this syntax. Try the following (`=` instead of `:` separating key-value pairs).

```
<cfset convertYesNo = {
    YES = "YES ",
    NO = "NO "
}>
```

Comment: This is second error that I'm getting. Do you know why this would show in CF9: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 13714 of the JSON data

Comment: @espresso_coffee I am not sure of the context. Without looking at the code I cannot say anything for sure/

Answer (score 1):

> `<cfset qryRecs['value'] = URLEncodedFormat(structKeyExists(convertYesNo, myInfo[CurrentRow]) ? convertYesNo[myInfo[CurrentRow]] : myInfo[CurrentRow])>`

Structs (HashTables) are great at fast finding of keys, but you only have 2 key here, so a much more efficient construct would be (example in cfscript syntax):

```
qryRecs['value'] = URLEncodedFormat(
    listFindNoCase("YES,NO", myInfo[CurrentRow]) ?
        uCase(myInfo[CurrentRow]) & " "
            :
        myInfo[CurrentRow]
);
```

Though for better readability and code maintenance you should consider to break it into multiple statements:

```
value = myInfo[CurrentRow];
if (value == "YES" || value == "NO")          // use EQ operator in CFML syntax
    value = uCase(value) & " ";

qryRecs['value'] = URLEncodedFormat(value);
```